# Why solr spatial/geofilt omit other fq condition?

Tags: solr, spatial, date-range, spatial-query

I am a starter with Solr. Following is my fq query-

```
{!geofilt pt=43.653226,-79.38318429999998 sfield=lat_lon d=100} AND -(start_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z] AND end_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z])
```

My Query target is finding all items within 100 KM from given LatLon where no start_date or end_date fall in the date range [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z]. Here start_date and end_date are multivalued fields. BUT it doesn't filter with that date range. It does when i remove GEOFILT option as below-

```
-(start_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z] AND end_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z])
```

Even it works with other fq condition but not GEOFILT.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the !geofilt inside a `_query_:""` wrapper like this:

```
_query_:"{!geofilt pt=43.653226,-79.38318429999998 sfield=lat_lon d=100}" AND -(start_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z] AND end_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z])
```